# Can't install xgboost from CRAN

Tags: r, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xgboost

when i want to install  xgboost from cran in cenos7 (which is wsl2) i got this error, and i can not find any clue by google the message:

```
In file included from amalgamation/xgboost-all0.cc:68:0:
amalgamation/../src/learner.cc: In member function ‘virtual void xgboost::LearnerImpl::SaveModel(xgboost::Json*) const ’:
amalgamation/../src/learner.cc:378:24: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘xgboost::Json&’ from an rvalue of type ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’
     Json& out { *p_out };
                        ^
amalgamation/../src/learner.cc: In member function ‘virtual void xgboost::LearnerImpl::SaveConfig(xgboost::Json*) cons
’:
amalgamation/../src/learner.cc:441:24: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘xgboost::Json&’ from an rvalue of type ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’
     Json& out { *p_out };
                        ^
make: *** [amalgamation/xgboost-all0.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xgboost’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/xgboost’
```

the env is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0 tools_3.6.0
```

default gcc version is 4.8.5 and  in order to compile 'rstan'  I  write

```
CXX14 = g++ -std=c++1y
CXX14FLAGS += -fPIC
```

into file ~/.R/Makevars

How can I install xgboost successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the dev package from github (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#installing-the-development-version):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DR_LIB=ON
make -j$(nproc)
make install
```

When default target is used, an R package shared library would be built in the build area. The install target, in addition, assembles the package files with this shared library under build/R-package and runs R CMD INSTALL.

Comment: thanks for your solution, i follow your steps  when i run cmake. i find i haven't install it .i install cmake3  and run ' cmake3 .. -DR_LIB=ON' error happened .  sad it need gcc 5+. i realized that  maybe  i find the reason. then i update gcc to 7 and install xgboost from cran everything is ok now.   thanks again!